# How do you make testing not boring?

Tags: language-agnostic, testing

Just as the title said. What ways do you use to test your own code so that it wouldn't be a boring task? Do you use any tool? For my projects, I use a spreadsheet to list all the possible routines i.e. from the basic CRUD and also all the weird routines. i make about 10 routines.

I get about 2-3 bugs and sometimes major ones by doing this. And if i'm not doing this the client reports another bug.

So tell me what technique do you use in testing your own code in such a way that it doesn't bore you?

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that i am particularly working on web based apps and my language is PHP & Cakephp framework.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have fast tests. The (more) immediate feedback helps to acchieve short iterations. This can almost make you addicted to starting the next test run.

Comment: Sorry but what exactly are fast test? do you mean short automated tests?

Comment: I'd consider fast tests as automated test that don't take minutes but rather seconds to complete. This way you can trigger the tests virtually after every change.

Comment: Generic answer: It depends ;-)
In general you will end up with a hierarchy of tests. These range from very short unit tests (~ miliseconds) to longer running scenario based system tests (a few minutes).
Besides that you might have load/performance/stability tests that can run for days. But that is different topic.
The key to short-running tests is to test everything at the lowest level possible. For example not to use a DB when you just want to test some calculation method.

Answer (score 10):

If you find testing boring this is because testing your code is a necessary evil...   least is how I perceived you see it.

All you need here is a change in your point of view towards testing... and more specifically... a change in HOW you are testing.  You love programming a lot more than testing... well  program your tests...  then it is just as fun as programming the thing to begin with... and when you are done you have

1. a program that works
2. a test suite that remains and test it every builds

So leave that excel sheet and step by step debugger and join the fun :-)

Of course there is more to that and this where test frameworks (junit, testNG, Dunit, NUnit ...) will come in handy, they will take the little pains away and only leave the coding part of the test..

Happy coding and by extension.. happy testing :-)

---

Few references you may find useful, I am not a PHP expert, far from it but it seemed to fit the purpose.

- http://www.simpletest.org/
- http://www.phpunit.de/
- http://laughingmeme.org/2003/08/05/a-few-tips-for-writing-useful-libraries-in-php/

Comment: I couldn't agree more. The testing, and the refactoring, that follows is anything but boring.

Comment: Good answer! It's like we party and get excited after several hours writing the new code/fix that's until we test it and "It's not really working!" there goes the party pooper.

Answer (score 8):

I used to think the same as you.  When I first started programming, we had to work out what the output would be on paper and then do visual comparisons of the actual and expected output.  Talk about tedious.  A couple of years ago, I discovered Test Driven Development and xUnit and now I love tests.

Basically, in TDD, you have a framework designed to allow you to write tests and run them very easily.  So, writing tests just becomes writing code.  The process is:

1. Just write enough to allow you to write a test.  E.g you're adding a method to a class, so you just write the method sig and any return statement needed to get it to compile.
2. Then you write your first test and run the framework to see that it fails.
3. Then you add code to/refactor your method to get the test to pass.
4. Then you add the next test and see that it fails.
5. Repeat 3 and 4 until you can't think of any more tests.
6. You've finished.

That's one of the nice things about TDD: once your code passes every test you can think of, you know you're finished - without TDD, sometimes it's difficult to know when to stop.  Where do your tests come from?  They come from the spec.  TDD often helps you to realise that the spec. is full of holes as you think of test cases for things that weren't in the spec.  You can get these questions answered before you start writing the code to deal with them.

Another nice thing is that when you discover a bug later, you can start reworking your code safe in the knowledge that all of the existing tests will prove your code still works for all the known cases, whilst the new tests you've written to recreate the bug will show you when you've fixed it.

You can add unit tests to existing code - just add them for the bits you're changing.  As you keep coming back to it, the tests will get more and more coverage.

xUnit is the generic name for a bunch of frameworks that support different languages: JUnit for Java, NUnit for .NET, etc.  There's probably already one for whatever language you use.  You can even [write your own framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530).  Read this book - it's excellent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have worked on Unit tests before. the reason why i am not using them now is because I was assuming pen and paper (or spreadsheet) is faster. Because from my experience unit tests becomes obsolete quickly I mean when changes happen it makes asserts fail. then i have to fix bugs in unit tests also.

Comment: No, you should change the unit tests (and the 'Asserts') first. Then your tests will fail and you will be forced to change the system to pass your tests.

You should always be thinking, "Test First"

Comment: I agree with gommo.  You should change the tests first.  Also, this could be a symptom that your tests are doing too much.  I always try to have only one Assert per test.  And I try to test the smallest thing I can.  If you're making a big chaqnge and every test you have for a method needs to change, then effectively you're writing a new method.

Answer (score 3):

For new code, work out what the code should do, write a test that asserts that the code does it, work out how to do it, then write the code.

For finding bugs in existing code, a test which reproduces the bug makes it easier to test.

This isn't boring, because in both cases the tests have a high likelihood of failure.

For UAT, then I haven't found any non-boring way - you go through the requirements one by one and make as many tests are required for the functionality. Ideally for new projects, that would have been mostly done up-front as part of the elaboration, but not always. It's only when you're writing tests after the fact that you have to a long list of tests which you already know will pass that it gets boring.

Comment: Exactly. It gets boring when i already know that it will pass and i have 9 more to go.

Answer (score 3):

I dont see how it can be boring since it's a large part of the programming itself. Finding and removing bugs is very important, but if you think it's boring maybe you would rather write code in which case you can write a few lines that test critical parts in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a test first approach \ pair programming test first.

If you writing them after you have written your own code, then your target is to find mistakes in your work = sad target.

Conversely, if you write your tests before you code, then your target is to write flawless software = happy target.

Answer (score 2):

"No testing, no boring."

Comment: I dont agree with you. No testing is OK unless it is used only by the author.

Answer (score 2):

Write **automatic** unit tests, with [PhpUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) or [Simpletest](http://www.simpletest.org/) since you're using PHP, or any other [unit-testing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks) available for your language of choice. Following [Test-Driven Development](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestDrivenDevelopment) (TDD), you will build a test suite along with your code. You won't have the impression you're testing anything. Really.

"* test a little, code a little*".

Answer (score 1):

I try to write my Tests first and try to design the class around it. So i am really test focussed. I am using JUnit etc.

If you try Programming in that way..testing becomes more and more fun, from my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

One of the advices I give to my team is that concerning a new features 90% of the logic should run out of the context of the application.

Features that can run outside of the application context are always easy to test.

If you are using .net, you can investigate [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.5).

You can also look at [Pex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/cc950525.aspx). It seems to be an amazing test framework.

However, your question is a little generic because there are a lot testing types.

Have fun testing :).

Answer (score 1):

I work for a small company yet we have a separate test team. This is because developers are often blind for their own errors, thus they tend to be bad testers.
Our test team is made up of experienced Test Engineers who work according to predefined test-plans and who often use automated test-tools to test the applications we create. (Including websites!) They are **not** developers!
These testers use [TMap](http://eng.tmap.net/Home/) for the automated testing. The rest is just manual labor, reading the functional designs and making sure that whatever is mentioned in the functional design will work *exactly* as described in the final version.
Any errors are reported back to the developers by using an internal bug reporting tool.

Answer (score 1):

Write some unit tests/automated tests, which will run automatically e.g. after a new build has been done. 

Use encapsulation and try to test against interfaces only.

Write some small tools to help you test your modules/classes.

Answer (score 1):

Making an easy to use, test suite is easy to do for Perl programs. There is a standard way to do testing in Perl using the [Test Anything Protocol](http://testanything.org/).

Basically you write a bunch of files with the `.t` extension, in the `t/` directory of your project, and then run [`prove`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Harness/bin/prove).

The files in `t/` basically look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 8;

use Date::ICal;

$ical = Date::ICal->new( year => 1964, month => 10, day => 16, 
                         hour => 16, min => 12, sec => 47, 
                         tz => '0530' );

ok( defined $ical,            'new() returned something' );
ok( $ical->isa('Date::ICal'), "  and it's the right class" );
is( $ical->sec,     47,       '  sec()'   );
is( $ical->min,     12,       '  min()'   );    
is( $ical->hour,    16,       '  hour()'  );
is( $ical->day,     17,       '  day()'   );
is( $ical->month,   10,       '  month()' );
is( $ical->year,    1964,     '  year()'  );
```

For more information you can read the [tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Simple/lib/Test/Tutorial.pod).

There are many languages which have modules designed to work with The [TAP](http://testanything.org/), have a look [here](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=site%3Atestanything.org%20TAP%20Producers) for more information.

Unfortunately, TAP has only recently been used for other languages than Perl, so there isn't as much support for them, as there exists for Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Do not write tests for trivial stuff - at least not until it breaks i.e. on rare occasion. If you do then you will feel discomfort every time you need to come and maintain those tests. It's absolutely normal, boredom laziness frustration etc. is your natural instinct reaction to pointless work.

Quite opposite, writing tests for non-trivial algorithms & logic, discovering corner cases which you didn't even think about is actually fun and very rewarding experience.